# Low-Fare endpoint returning JSON with missing operating.carrierCode

Tags: amadeus

The Low-fare endpoint just recently started returning JSON with some flight segments missing a key-value pair for operating.carrierCode, for example:

```
"operating": {
                  "number": “5898"
```

This was the second flight segment of the first result (data[0].offerItems[0].services[0].segments[1].flightSegment) when yesterday I searched:

https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=LON&destination=PAE&departureDate=2019-10-29&returnDate=2019-11-13&adults=1&nonStop=false&max=50

Here it is in context:

`{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "flight-offer",
      "id": "1564934270644-1482530186",
      "offerItems": [
        {
          "services": [
            {
              "segments": [
                {
                  "flightSegment": {
                    "departure": {
                      "iataCode": "LHR",
                      "terminal": "2",
                      "at": "2019-10-29T09:20:00Z"
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                      "iataCode": "SFO",
                      "terminal": "I",
                      "at": "2019-10-29T13:30:00-07:00"
                    },
                    "carrierCode": "SN",
                    "number": "9101",
                    "aircraft": {
                      "code": "777"
                    },
                    "operating": {
                      "carrierCode": "UA",
                      "number": "9101"
                    },
                    "duration": "0DT11H10M"
                  },
                  "pricingDetailPerAdult": {
                    "travelClass": "ECONOMY",
                    "fareClass": "K",
                    "availability": 4,
                    "fareBasis": "KLP5ULGT"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "flightSegment": {
                    "departure": {
                      "iataCode": "SFO",
                      "terminal": "3",
                      "at": "2019-10-29T16:15:00-07:00"
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                      "iataCode": "PAE",
                      "at": "2019-10-29T18:32:00-07:00"
                    },
                    "carrierCode": "UA",
                    "number": "5898",
                    "aircraft": {
                      "code": "E7W"
                    },
                    "operating": {
                      "number": “5898”
                    },
                    "duration": "0DT2H17M"
                  },
                  "pricingDetailPerAdult": {
                    "travelClass": "ECONOMY",
                    "fareClass": "K",
                    "availability": 9,
                    "fareBasis": "KLP5ULGT"
                  }
                }
              ]
…`

Is this a known bug? It was pretty easy to write a workaround, but I was surprised that this data was missing since it had been working correctly for months.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with the operating carrier even in cryptic mode
FLT/DATE       RTNG   CKIN TM DEP   ARR     TM EQP ML    DURA  DIST

UA5898 Y 29OCT SFOPAE      3  415P  632P       E7W G     2:17   711
                 SFOPAE OPERATED BY SKYWEST DBA UNITED EXPRES

>

Whilst at shopping using enterprise apis you can use the same text describing the schedule data resumed by flight number.
Dont know of any parameter to get it in the api response too.